# Spring4 boot unittest @ActiveProfiles causing failed to load applicationContext error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to provide different database for running unitTest than using default production database. I thought about using profile to solve this issue. 
This is spring4 boot project, so everything is annotated.
This is what I am doing:

Under src/main/resources, I put `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/services
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Under src/test/resources, I put application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/services_test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Hercules1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Then, I put `@ActiveProfiles("test")` before test, now when I run the unit test, I immediately meet this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

I googled quite a lot and nothing can solve this error.

Can you point out what's wrong with my solution?

Thanks

Comment: If all you're doing is using different properties in test and main, then don't bother with the profile. Just name the file `application.properties` and put it in `src/test/resources`. Assuming that you're using Maven, resources in that directory will override those in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Please share the whole error

Answer (score -2):

Just suffixing `-test` to `application.properties` will not make the properties a candidate for the profile that you activate. You need to do the following:

**A datasource configuration interface:**

```
public interface DatasourceConfig {
    public void setup();
}
```

**Test Datasource configuration:**

```
@Component
@Profile("test")
public class ProductionDatasourceConfig implements DatasourceConfig {
    @Override
    public void setup() {
        // Set up your test datasource
    }
}
```

**Production datasource configuration:**

```
@Component
@Profile("prod")
public class ProductionDatasourceConfig implements DatasourceConfig {
    @Override
    public void setup() {
        // Set up your prod datasource
    }
}
```

**Activate the profile:**

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

**Inject the datasource based on environment:**

```
@Autowired
DatasourceConfig datasourceConfig;
```

Beans declared in XML can also be mapped to the profile as below:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="devDatasourceConfig" class="org.profiles.DevDatasourceConfig" />
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
    <bean id="productionDatasourceConfig" class="org.profiles.ProductionDatasourceConfig" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, very accurate! This is the only and best answer acrossing all the internet. I don't know why spring doc never mentioned this at all. Thanks again.

Comment: Assuming that you're using Spring Boot, suffixing "-test" to the properties **is** sufficient. So none of the above is necessary. I guess that's why it's not in the docs...